# Amazon S3 path or to_file wont work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, paperclip

Hey guys ive got the following code in my Model

require 'RMagick'

class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :card

```
has_attached_file :photo,
                  :styles => {
                    :thumb => ["100x100", :jpg],
                    :pagesize => ["500x400", :jpg],
                  },
                  :storage => :s3,
                      :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml",
                      :path => ":attachment/:id/:style.:extension",
                      :bucket => 'your_deck',
                  :default_style => :pagesize

attr_accessor :x1, :y1, :width, :height

def update_attributes(att)

  scaled_img = Magick::ImageList.new(self.photo.path)
  orig_img = Magick::ImageList.new(self.photo.path(:original))
  scale = orig_img.columns.to_f / scaled_img.columns

  args = [ att[:x1], att[:y1], att[:width], att[:height] ]
  args = args.collect { |a| a.to_i * scale }

  orig_img.crop!(*args)
  orig_img.write(self.photo.path(:original))

  self.photo.reprocess!
  self.save

  super(att)
end
```

end

This code works offline however when on Heroku with Amazon S3 it fails to work, ive tried the code with to_file and it also wont work

I get the following error

can't convert Array into String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and it's due to an [update](http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/commit/1fef4c302d076575a1ca9691e01eb96ee9262ebc#commitcomment-166133) to paperclip. I'm surprised heroku are still using this gem version as it will surely affect all their users; I installed a previous version as a plugin and it's fine. Don't forget to remove the gem from your .gems file or specify the previous version in your gems manifest.